# LaTeX Warning: Reference `@' on page xxx undefined on input line

Tags: bibliographies

I really do not know how to ask this question.
I am trying to compile a tex document (`\documentclass[a4paper]{report}`), in which for the bibliography I have to include many references whose bibtex format is like:

```
@ARTICLE{Zand+94,
author = {{in 't Zand}, J.~J.~M. and {Heise}, J. and {Jager}, R.},
title = "{The optimum open fraction of coded apertures. With an application to the wide field X-ray cameras of SAX}",
journal = {\aap},
keywords = {INSTRUMENTATION: DETECTORS, TECHNIQUES: IMAGE PROCESSING, TELESCOPES, X-RAYS: GENERAL},
 year = 1994,
month = aug,
volume = 288,
pages = {665-674},
adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994A\%26A...288..665I},
adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

To define the journal, I have found [this official website](http://doc.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty) where definitions of the journals abbreviations are given as `\def\aap{\ref@jnl{A\&A}}`.

However, when I compile with `pdflatex` `bibtex` (a variable number of times), I receive the warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `@' on page 35 undefined on input line 92.
```

for each reference where the voice `journal` is included in the bibtex text.
The line `92` is where the command `printbibliography` is given in the main tex file.

As a consequence of the warning, the reference in the bibliography is mispelled:

```
in ’t Zand, J. J. M., J. Heise, and R. Jager (Aug. 1994). “The optimum
open fraction of coded apertures. With an application to the wide field
X-ray cameras of SAX”. In: ??jnlA&A 288, pp. 665–674.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that you are extracting only some lines from the package you
linked in your question.  the definitions there are encoded with "internal"
notation, using `@` as a "letter" for the duration of reading in that
`\sty` file.

unless you are loading the complete package with `\usepackage`, you need
to treat the extracted lines as if they were being read in with the
`\usepackage` conventions.  as mentioned in several comments, and a linked
potential duplicate, the way to do this is to wrap the extracted lines
between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`.

this code takes care of the underlying style definitions and the one
command for a journal abbreviation that you cite in your question.  it
should go into your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\let\jnl@style=\rm
\def\ref@jnl#1{{\jnl@style#1}}

\def\aap{\ref@jnl{A\&A}}                % Astronomy and Astrophysics
\makeatother
```

if you need to add more journal definitions, be sure to insert them
before the line `\makeatother`.

Comment: I did tried this before, but now it seems to work properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You make it hard to give a definitive answer as you have only posted disjointed fragments but I would guess that you have

```
\def\aap{\ref@jnl{A\&A}}
```

not

```
\makeatletter
\def\aap{\ref@jnl{A\&A}}
\makeatother
```

If `@` is a letter then `\ref@jnl` is a single command, hopefully defined somewhere in your package or class file.

If `@` is not a letter then `\ref@jnl` is equivalent to `\ref {@}jnl` and so will generate an errror about an unknown `\label` `@`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry, I do not understand your guess anyway. What is `\makeatletter`? Also, a definition of `\ref@jnl` is given in the link I posted, but not totally sure it works properly, how would you define it?

Comment: @Py-ser see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: I see. Should I surround `\def\ref@jnl#1{{\jnl@style#1}}` with those?

Comment: @Py-ser all such things should really be in a package (where @ is automatically a letter, but for one off use if you are defining them in your document you need \makeatletter \makeatother around the block where you are defining or using `@` commands

Comment: Thanks. There is no package, I have copied in my main tex file those definitions that I took from the link. Either I surround that line with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, or not, I still receive the error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\aap ->\ref@jnl 
                {A\&A}`
or `! Undefined control sequence.
\ref@jnl #1->{\jnl@style 
                         #1}`

Comment: @Py-ser sorry if you need more help you should fix the question to have a complete self contained document from `\documentclass` (preferably using `article`) to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the error. I can not guess what commands you have or what is wrong from fragments in comments.